# How a research project, taken on my own, of undergraduation will be valued?

Tags: research-undergraduate

I’m from a south asian country, and here neither the universities nor the governmental agencies (who regulate educational guidlines) have any provision for undergrads to write a **thesis**, they simply require them to pass the annual exams, and a few assignments (for internal markings).

I talked to my professor regarding undergraduate thesis, but he replied that the university doesn’t have any rule or requirements for undergrads writing a thesis. I asked him can I undertake a research on my own, and then have it ceritfied by him as regard to its merit (as my professor is a PhD.) to which he replied that that such a thing won’t be a thesis as the university doesn’t have provisions for it, it would rather be called a project (mind you, he hesitated to call it a research project) and even after its ceritfication by him it won’t carry much value.

I would like to ask, in Germany undergrads are required to write thesis and they themselves are of the view that their thesis doesn’t give out any **new knowledge** to the world, their thesis can be said to be a new way or a different way of looking at the things already known, but then they get this advantage that their admission chances in reputed graduate schools gets up, as their application form by that thesis becomes stronger. How can I, whose university doesn’t have provisions for undergrad thesis and is also not a reputed one from a developed country, make my application stronger in matters of research? Will a research project, taken on my own and certified by my professor regarding its merit, be a total trash?

Comment: Possibly this depends on the country (and even the university) where you wish to later study, and possibly also the field. For what it's worth, in the U.S. this is something one would have the professor involved discuss in that professor's letter of recommendation. Moreover, someone who does something like this when not required for graduation would probably stand out -- other things equal -- as compared to those who had no choice but to write a thesis.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro "For what it's worth, in the U.S. this is something one would have the professor involved discuss in that professor's letter of recommendation”

In my country the system of LoR doesn’t exist, should I simply request my professor to do it  for me (by informing him about my aimed University) and he would _somehow_ manage it? 

By the way, as of current situations, I’m aiming for U.K. universities, but they don’t differ very much from those of U.S.

Comment: I don't know enough about U.K. universities to advise you, but others here might. Worth considering is how much writing a thesis will help you towards your later study and research, and not just in getting admitted somewhere, since the people looking at your application will be judging your potential for success and likely can [see through](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/see-through_1) attempts to [game the system](https://plainenglish.com/expressions/game-the-system/), although I think writing a thesis will almost surely help towards later study and research.